# How to decrease the snapshotting time in QEMU/KVM?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

I am using QEMU snapshots of disc as well as ram(combined) using QEMU GUI and terminal(using virsh command). My guest VMs have 1 gb RAM each. The snapshots work very fine for my work but there is a problem.

The problem is that each snapshot takes around 2 seconds which is very large for my work. Is there any way to decrease this time?

Comment: How quickly do you require? It is going to take some amount of time to quiesce guest file systems and take the snapshot.  Possibly a faster storage system would help.

Answer (score 0):

The time required to take a snapshot is going to largely depend on the speed of the storage on the host to which the snapshot is being written. So the main way to increase speed is to improve speed of your storage, possibly by changing what storage is used. It is hard to give more specific advice without knowing more about your host configuration & the way you're doing the snapshots.